# web3.js: sendAndConfirmTransaction hangs on devnet

Tags: web3.js

I am trying to send a simple transaction to transfer funds. When I invoke `sendAndConfirmTransaction` it just hangs and never returns.

I've tried configuring a few options in the command but that doesn't change anything. Here is the command I am sending:

```
    const tx = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transferTransaction, [signer], {skipPreflight: true, maxRetries: 1})
```

Is there a way to see where the SDK is getting stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solana devnet was down for the past few days which is most likely the cause of your issue, not anything on your side.

You can stay updated at https://explorer.solana.com/?cluster=devnet

Generally, if the ping goes into the red, devnet is unusable.

Comment: That was it! fwiw I had checked the url `https://api.devnet.solana.com/haproxy_status` and that had showed a `200 OK`, even though it was unavailable.